# C++ Error in stdlib cdefs.h?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I keep getting an error while trying to compile my C++ app on Mac Lion (10.7) with XCode.
The compiler complains about a line in `cdefs.h` (included from `syslog.h`) with an error `expected unqualified-id`.

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define __BEGIN_DECLS   extern "C" { //<--- Error in this line
#define __END_DECLS }
#else
#define __BEGIN_DECLS
#define __END_DECLS
#endif
```

Whats up here?

Comment: Is it the only error? Doesn't the compiler show any other message? (warning or whatever)?

Comment: Are you sure the error is at that line? If so, are you sure there are no errors (unclosed braces, missing semicolons at the end of classes, etc) _above_ where you #include the file?

Comment: `cdefs.h` is included via `syslog.h` which I included. There is another error in `syslog.h` at the line `__BEGIN_DECLS` - same error message. If I comment out `#include <syslog.h>` in my project, everything is fine.

Comment: Does the compiler also indicate that the error occurred during a macro substitution? Is there another line indicator showing the `__BEGIN_DECLS` usage which caused the `#define` to be used? If so, that is valuable context.

Comment: @k_wave `cdefs.h` is included indirectly by almost any platform header. So you likely still get this line even when commenting out `#include <syslog.h>`.

Comment: Can you please post the exact error encountered? Actually I would recommend posting all of them, as well as the portion of the source file that have the #include's listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it guys!
There was some weird invisible char in the line after `#include <syslog.h>`. So commenting out this line fixed it because that char was also commented out.
Conclusion: you shouldn't copy n' paste everything found in the web.

Comment: I was missing a semicolon from a header file that I was including in multiple files...

Comment: I was missing a semicolon in a header included before a different header which itself kicked off an entire chain of includes. What an incredibly arcane and unhelpful error message.